# PHP Mail Sending on some webpages

Tags: php, email, gmail

This code is for my contact page and it spits out an email that I can read with gmail.

```
<?php
$message = "Sender:" . "\r\n" . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n" . "\r\n" . "Company Name:" . "\r\n" . $_POST["company"] . "\r\n" . "\r\n" .'Message:' . "\r\n" . $_POST["message"];

$to = "EMAIL ADDRESS TAKEN OUT FOR SECURITY PURPOSES, IT'S LEGIT";
$subject = $_POST["title"];
$body = $message; 

$headers = 'From:' . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To:'  . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    echo("<p class='form'>You're message was sent successfully! We'll get back to you shortly. In the mean-time... ");
} else {
echo("<p class='form'>Oops! There was an error sending your message.");
}
?>
```

However, when I put this code into another page...

```
    $message = "Hey, testing this. Go to this link <a href='WEB ADDRESS HIDDEN=" .$display ."'>Activate</a>" ;

$subject = "Activate your Account";

if (mail($email, $subject, $message))
{
echo "A verification link was sent to <strong>".$email."</strong>";
}
```

It doesn't send the email! $email is a variable that I used before to insert into a database. The user inputted it. After that I send an email to them but it's not sending. Mail() returns true because it prints the text with the correct email address as well.

What's wrong here? Any suggestions?

I'm new to php so.. try to speak as if you were learning for the first time.

Thanks!

EDIT:

The variables are not related. They don't talk. They have the same names but exist on different pages that have no relation to each other.

Answer (score 0):

After the colons (":") ion From, X-Mailer etc, there should be a space.

```
$headers = 'From: ' . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '  . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Additionally, make sure that the "To" is formatted correctly.

What is the value of `$email` on the second page? Has it been correctly set?

Finally, what server is this running on? Could it be that the default `From:` email address is not valid (and that is why the code on the first page is working as expected, because it is setting a correct `From` email address?).

Comment: The first code worked before. The second piece of code exists on a different page and doesn't work. I updated it however just because I can. :)

Comment: OK. What about the server details? Is the from email address OK by default, because there is no headers being sent on the second page.

Answer (score 0):

the `$email` variable has to exist on both pages, which means you have to transfer it to the second script somehow, either by `$_GET` or `$_SESSION`

on your first script

```
// put this at the very top of the script to start a session
<?php
session_start();

// then, do your stuff and, after you set your $email variable, se a session
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
```

on your second script

```
<?php
session_start();
$email = $_SESSION['email'];

// do your other stuff, then send your email...
mail($email, $subject, $message);
```

Comment: The variables aren't related and are discarded after one use. I updated the main topic to be sure everyone sees it. Thanks for the response.

Comment: OK. Are you sure gmail isn't just slow right now? Have you tried using another email address on a different service?